# Get Video By Id to check status using the YouTubeApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube .net API to upload videos to a single channel.
I am using the Direct Upload with this code:

```
 Video newVideo = new Video();

            newVideo.Title = poi.Title;
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Travel", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
            newVideo.Keywords = "my key words";
            newVideo.Description = "my description";
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("path to video");
            Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

The video is uploading fine and when I call createdVideo.Status.Name I get "processing" which I would expect.
What I need to know is when the video has finished processing and if it has been accepted so I can tell the user.

I will do this asynchronously and intending in just calling the video periodically and checking it's status then displaying in a grid when it's live.

The documentation appears to miss that step, and doesn't tell me how to get my video back by Id.

I am obviously missing something, so can someone tell me How do I get my video by Id?

Answer (score 0):

The YouTubeUploader sample included in the client library uploads video asynchronously:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fclients%2Fcs%2Fsamples%2FYouTubeUploader

The `YouTubeUploader.InsertVideo` method (http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/YouTubeUploader/YouTubeUploader/insertandretry.cs#134) starts the process and you listen to the `AsyncOperationCompleted` and `AsyncOperationProgress` events of the `ResumableUploader` component to track the status of the upload:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/YouTubeUploader/YouTubeUploader/insertandretry.cs#94